# What does the LIN break detection flag mean for ARM STM32 devices?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

There is a UART error flag in the STM32F4xx series that is

> Bit 8 LBD: the LIN break detection flag

There is no further information on this.  What does this mean in terms of UART?

Comment: it means a break was detected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reference manual RM0090:

> **LIN reception**
>
> A break detection circuit is implemented on the USART interface. The
>   detection is totally independent from the normal USART receiver. A
>   break can be detected whenever it occurs, during Idle state or during
>   a frame.
>
> When the receiver is enabled (RE=1 in USART_CR1), the circuit looks at
>   the RX input for a start signal. The method for detecting start bits
>   is the same when searching break characters or data. After a start bit
>   has been detected, the circuit samples the next bits exactly like for
>   the data (on the 8th, 9th and 10th samples). If 10 (when the LBDL = 0
>   in USART_CR2) or 11 (when LBDL=1 in USART_CR2) consecutive bits are
>   detected as ‘0, and are followed by a delimiter character, the LBD
>   flag is set in USART_SR. If the LBDIE bit=1, an interrupt is
>   generated. Before validating the break, the delimiter is checked for
>   as it signifies that the RX line has returned to a high level.
>
> If a ‘1 is sampled before the 10 or 11 have occurred, the break
>   detection circuit cancels the current detection and searches for a
>   start bit again.
>
> If the LIN mode is disabled (LINEN=0), the receiver continues working
>   as normal USART, without taking into account the break detection.
>
> If the LIN mode is enabled (LINEN=1), as soon as a framing error
>   occurs (i.e. stop bit detected at ‘0, which will be the case for any
>   break frame), the receiver stops until the break detection circuit
>   receives either a ‘1, if the break word was not complete, or a
>   delimiter character if a break has been detected.

Comment: I'm not clear on the delimiter part.  What delimiter character?  The LBD flag seems to get set regardless of any delimiter character.  "Before validating the break, the delimiter is check for as it signifies the RX line has returned to a high level."  So does that mean the RX line has to go high before LBDF is set to one?   Not just after 10 low bit periods?  What is a delimiter and what is a break word?  Is a break word 10 bits of zeros?  I assume the frame error flag needs to be cleared as well.  Not very clear documentation.